# Canon EOS SDK | threaded EdsDownloadEvfImage problems

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety, edsdk, canon-sdk

so basically I am having problems when trying to run EdsDownloadEvfImage from the Canon EOS SDK on a separate thread. The program then does... unexpected things, freezes, etc.

Basically, what it does is that the worker thread freezes on EdsDownloadEvfImage when trying to lock a mutex from main thread, which is simply mind-blowing for me.

I've found out that doing any of the EdsOpenSession, EdsCreateMemoryStream, etc. on a thread is an absolute killer, but that doesn't mind, the only really time-consuming operation is that image download.

Based on the documenatation, I've ensured that the worker thread has

```
CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED )
```

called before the download. I've also tried it without it and it was without any difference. Maybe there's some problem with executing this function?

Or would a working alternative be running the entire EDSDK on a worker thread? (with initializeSDK etc.)

Thanks for reponses.

Btw: I'm using the SDK in a Qt application.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I just put everything on a separate thread and now it's working fine.